# How can i read a file in a ftp server using a servlet and then send this as a downloadable file to the user?

Tags: java, servlets, ftp, apache-commons-net

I have developed a servlet that offers some services.
I am using apache-commons-net FTPClient to log into a ftp server and read a file.

I want to make this file downloadle (aka send it to the outputstream maybe?) , but the only ways of reading a file that i know of are:
FTPClient.retrieveFileStream(String remote) and FTPClient.retrieveFile(String remote, OutputStream local).

I tried the first one and then wrote the InputStream i got to the outputStream of the servlet:

```
    InputStream myFileStream = FTPClient.retrieveFileStream(fileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int length;
    resp.reset();
    resp.setContentType("text/csv");
    resp.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=\""+fileName+"\"");


    OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
    while((length=myFileStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
        out.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myFileStream.close();
    out.flush();
```

The Second One:

```
myClient.retrieveFile(fileName, resp.getOutputStream());
```

In both cases i get the text content of the file as a response and not the file itself.

Is there any way i can do this.

P.s. this code belongs to a medhod that is being called by the doPost()  with http req and  http resp as parameters.

Comment: Ehm, what is the difference between _the text content of the file_ and _the file itself_?

Comment: The difference is:
the file content is a text (aka the response is a text value) while i would want for the browser to initialize a file download at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i was using a google extension (DHC) to test my web service. and it displayed the file content instead of initializing the download.
I was making the file download in a doPost() method.

Solution:

I made it in a doGet() method and when accessed directly via browser everything works ok.
So i think it was only the extensions problem, which wrote the content of the response back to me instead of downloading the file attachment.

Thanks for the feedback to @Jozef

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download the file instead of just showing it, you have to change the content type you're sending to the browser (because it's browser's business to either display the data or save them as a file). Thus, do e.g.

```
resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
```

(instead of `text/csv`) to "hide" the real nature of the data from the browser and force it to save the data.